# Raspberry pi not sensing my keyboard and mouse!

Tags: keyboard

I accidentally spilled some water on the raspberry pi board, and it switched off and the HDMI stopped working.. I dried the board and connected it again, now everything was working fine except for a thunderbolt sign on the top-right corner of my screen, and also I couldn't control the pi using keyboard and mouse.

Comment: A shortcut is a shortcut is a shortcut. It may have damaged some chips ...

Answer (score 2):

Leave it in a dry warm place for a couple of days.  If it still doesn't work buy another.

Comment: Thanks, but if there is any other way please inform.. I don't want to lose it

Comment: It is not economical to repair.  You would need to find the exact point or points of failure.  That might take anything between a minute or a day of an experts time.  Even if that point or points were identified the cost of component(s) replacement might be greater than the cost of buying a new Pi.

Comment: Ohh... So are you sure that it is because of the water spill.?

Comment: Ok then I'll buy a new one